# Ruby - rails - ajax pagination

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This isn't making ajax call. I guess its the javascript, on the console the request shows as 'html' rather than 'JS'. I have similar javascripts working for other ajax, but dont know what is wrong here.

_list_page.html.erb

```
<div class="digg_pagination">
    <div class="page_info">
      <%= page_entries_info @list_page %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @list_page, :container => true, ,  :remote => true %>
  </div>
```

JS gets rendered in list_page.js.erb file -

```
$(".pagination a").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: $(this).attr("href")
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**EDIT:** Tried jQuery bind, didn't work. For some reason click event is no binding with the element.

```
$(".pagination a").bind('click', function(event) {
alert('User clicked on "test"'); # Even this isn't working
 $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: $(this).attr("href")
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting why are you making explicitly ajax call with will_paginate , this feature is in-build with this gem . You can use :renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer" to make it ajax call .

like :

```
<%= will_paginate @events, :renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer",:remote => {, :update => "events_container", :loading => visual_effect(:appear, "loader"),:complete =>visual_effect(:fade,"loader" ) } %>
```

for more detail take a look on : http://www.botvector.net/2008/08/willpaginate-on-ajax.html

Comment: Hmmm. Let me try that again. Last time it game an error "Undefined constant' for `:renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer"`

Comment: True @gwane, will_paginate or kaminari

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant RemoteLinkRenderer):` for `:renderer => "RemoteLinkRenderer"`

Comment: check it out for will_paginate and rails version : https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce/issues/10

Comment: Hmmm. Not getting anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373041/1285061). 
will_paginate is not updated to work with Rails 3.